# Py2neo create node from object

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Can someone help me with how to create a node from an object? e.g. we have object schema something like

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
```

and I want to create py2neo Node `Node("Person", name="John", surname="Doe")`
, however, I want to generalize this so I can use it with multiple schemas to something like
`Node(type(obj), **obj)` but actually working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `py2neo.ogm` module, as this is exactly what it is intended for. There are details of this in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your creation logic to:

```
def create_node(obj):
    return Node(type(obj).__name__, **obj.__dict__)
```

Saving stays the same.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not very experienced with python so I didn't realize this solution.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've solved it like this:

```
    def create(self, obj):
        obj_props = {}
        for property, value in vars(obj).items():
            obj_props[property] = value

        node = Node(type(obj).__name__, **obj_props)
        tx = self.graph.begin()
        tx.create(node)
        tx.commit()
```

However, if anyone has a better solution I'm willing to learn.